# How to get the rss feed of github release , only latest release, exclude pre release?

Tags: github, rss, github-api

For bitcoin, the release page:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases
I can get github release rss seed by append ".atom" on it
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases.atom
But this will include pre release tags.
How can I get latest release tag only?

Answer (score 11):

Pre-releases are listed in the `releases.atom` feed, but they are not marked as pre-releases (no way to separate a pre-release from a final release as far as I can tell).

This information is instead available from the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/).

Comment: `releases.atom` now includes pre-releases.

Comment: Can you point to an example? I've just tested it on a repo w/ a pre-release but still don't see anything to indicate that status.

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/home-assistant/core/releases.atom

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link. I believe this has always been true. Pre-releases are _listed_, but there is no way to differentiate a pre-release from a final release in the RSS.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the noise and misunderstanding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to resort to the API.

unbelievable that such an essential feature is missing from the Atom feeds

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest `lastversion`?

The [lastversion](https://lastversion.getpagespeed.com/) utility is actually capable of detecting pre-releases from GitHub atom feeds alone, by looking at beta version identifiers in the tags.

It does use API as well for attempting to try returning more data from a release.